# How to determinate if agent/daemon has disabled or enabled state on OSX 10.6?

Tags: objective-c, macos, daemon

I need to determinate which agents and daemons are disabled on my OSX. Each process has plist file with parameters. I assume "Disabled" key is responsible for that. But not all agents/daemons has this value. So if property list doesn't contain this paramater it means it's disabled or enabled? I didn't find any info regarding default value for this item.

Please provide a reference to apple's documentation which proof it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Disabled" keys in each LaunchDaemon file can be overridden by an entry in /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist, and there's a similar system for LaunchAgents in /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.*userID*/overrides.plist. I don't think Apple has documented this anywhere, which means that you are not expected to interact directly with these files, just use `launchctl`. It also means they're subject to change (i.e. it didn't always work this way and might change without notice in a later version of OS X). Also, the file for LaunchDaemons is only readable by root.

Comment: I launch my app as root. So I can read all plist files. I just need to know if plist doesn't have "Disabled" key it means it's disabled or enabled by default?

Comment: If the "Disabled" key is not present, the job will be enabled by default (i.e. the default value of "Disabled" is false).

Comment: Gordon Davisson, is there any reference in documentation which proof it?

Comment: No, although it's implicit in the description in the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html): "Disabled <boolean> This optional key is used as a hint to launchctl(1) that it should not submit this job to launchd when loading a job or jobs." -- implying that the key can disable jobs, but that it is not necessary to explicitly set it false to enable a job.